# paintfunction drawing out of size of panel and starting in upper left corner

Tags: c#, panel, mandelbrot

I'm troubleshooting my program in which I want to draw the mandelbrot set, so I made it so it draws 1x1 rectangles on every pixel except it doesn't do every pixel, it only does 1 row.

I've already tried setting the y to 400 and subtracting until it reaches 0 but when I do that it draws a short line in de bottom left corner which doesn't even span the entire horizontal length of my panel. When I set y to -400 and add until it reaches 0 it doesn't even draw anything.
[y=0 and it adds until 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQrXY.png)

```
void Tekenmandel(object obj, PaintEventArgs pea)
            {
                int x = 0;
                int y = -400;
                while (y < 0)
                {
                    while (x < 400)
                    {
                        pea.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, 1, 1);
                        x++;
                    }
                    y++;
                }
            }
```

I want it to draw on every pixel (because I later want to draw the mandelbrot set) but it only draws on the first row.

Comment: You don't reset `x` to `0` to draw further lines (x stays `400`). Consider to use [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) statement instead of `while`.

Comment: @Sinatr I did what you said, (now I feel dumb because it was quite obvious I had to reset x to 0 every time) but now it just paints an inverted L (it's thicker than the previous line and it spans the whole width and length).

Answer (score 0):

okay I fixed it, it wasn't drawing on my panel but behind it, I still don't know how to draw on the panel but just drawing on the background works fine.